# R foreach function failed when executing in parallel

Tags: r

I am trying to execute many times a function using foreach and doParallel packages.

Here is an exemple of the function I built

```
loop<-function(x) {IND<-which(data2$id==unique(data1$id)[x]); c(
  id<-as.character(unique(data2[IND,"id"],na.rm=T)),
  var2<-as.numeric(sum(data2[IND,"var2"],na.rm=T)),
  var3<-as.numeric(rapply(data2[IND,"var3"],median,na.rm=T)))
```

And then the foreach loop using one core

```
result <- data.frame(foreach(i = 1:25000, .combine = rbind) %do% loop(i))
```

That works perfectly.

As the process is quit long, I tried to perform it using parallel function

```
cl <- makeCluster(11)
registerDoParallel(cl)
result <- data.frame(foreach(i = 1:25000, .combine = rbind) %dopar% loop(i))
stopCluster(cl)
```

This command unfortunately does not work and I get this error message :

```
Error in loop(i) : task 1 failed - "'object' must be a list"
```

Does someone would have an idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: First argument passed to `rapply` (`object`) must be a list.

Comment: It works ! thank you very much for your help !